# How can I use EF4 when I have existing POCO classes and existing tables with complex/custom map pings?

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-4, mapping

I have an existing (legacy) set of business objects (classes) that are based on ado.net. They have methods to load themselves from SQL server and methods to save themselves. This has existed long before EF or linq2sql.

I'd like to use EF and all the benefits it affords. The problem is my classes implement logic to load themselves uses custom logic that maps ado.net values to its properties. For example they may use 'T' and 'F' chars to map to bools or may pull out a CSV value which maps to a collection or may map varchar values to Enums. That's no problem to do in its .Load() method because all the logic to do that is written already. This app is very old.

For example my existing Customers class corresponds to a customer table but there's no way to map its values automatically.

Ideally I'd like to get to a point where I can use a data context and get an IQueryable result so I can use linq to query the database and save changes but when rows come out of the database I need to run some custom logic to get the class created.

So how can I use EF4 with an existing model and existing poco classes that require custom logic to map SQL values to properties (ie its existing .Load() and .Save() methods) in the least painful way possible?

Comment: Also workable would be if EF can call a method in my poco classes after instantiating them with the data set so I can ensure any custom mappings are set from the source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your entity classes have a `Initialize` method you can load the properties when EF materialize entities.

```
 public class YourContext : DbContext
 {
    protected ObjectContext ObjectContext
    {
        get
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        }
    }

    public YourContext(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
    {
        ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += ObjectMaterialized;
    }

    void ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic entity = e.Entity;
        entity.Initialize();
    }
 }
```